# Largest k such that p^k divides n

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, number-theory, built-in-symbols, prime-numbers

(Here all variables are integer.)

Is there a built-in function `f[n,p]` such that

```
f[n,p] = largest k such that p^k divides n
```

For example, f[120,2]=3, f[120,3]=1, f[120,5]=1, f[120,7]=0.

At present I am using self-made code:

```
f[n_, p_] :=
 If[Abs[p] >= 2,
  NestWhile[{#[[1]]/p, #[[2]] + 1} &, {n, 0}, IntegerQ[#[[1]]] &, 1,
    Infinity, -1][[2]], "Error"]
```

Note that using `FactorInteger` is a bad method. It takes too long time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`IntegerExponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerExponent.html)

```
IntegerExponent[120, #] & /@ {2, 3, 5, 7}

(* {3, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

Comment: Could also do `IntegerExponent[120, {2, 3, 5, 7}]`